# Python2.7 argparse require none or both options

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm trying to write a script that would when a user chooses to use an option (say --foo) they are then required to use another option (say --bar). Also, if they don't choose the --foo option the --bar option isn't required. The closest thing that I have found is the add_subparsers() method, but didn't seem to be for options, specifically.

What is the best way to accomplish this, if at all?

Comment: if you have the luxury of adding modules, check out docopt - http://docopt.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that type of thing a bit too complex for argparse to handle on it's own. What I do is something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--foo", action='store_true', help="Foos something. Must use --bar if --foo is used.")
parser.add_argument("--bar", action='store_true', help="Bars something.")

parsed_args = parser.parse_args()

if parsed_args.foo and not parsed_args.bar:
    sys.stderr.write("ERROR: Must use --bar if using --foo\n")
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)
```